# How to use 'quantmod' to get yahoo FX rate for a specific date?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using below code to get FX Rate

```
library(quantmod)
from <- c("CAD", "JPY", "USD")
to <- c("USD", "USD", "EUR")
getQuote(paste0(from, to, "=X"))
```

However, that gives me current quotes. How to get the quotes for a specific date, say 2019-7-20? It would be the best if you can modify based on the code I have instead of finding new functions. Thanks!

Comment: That day was a Saturday but try `getSymbols(paste0(from, to, "=X"), from = "2019-7-01", to = "2019-7-31")`.

Comment: doesn't matter if it's that date, 2019-7-22 is OK. from and to give us a time range, but I only want the FX rate for that one day

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the question, it is looking for the following.

```
getSymbols(paste0(from, to, "=X"), from = "2019-7-01", to = "2019-7-31")
#[1] "CADUSD=X" "JPYUSD=X" "USDEUR=X"

showSymbols()
#CADUSD=X JPYUSD=X USDEUR=X 
# "yahoo"  "yahoo"  "yahoo" 

head(`USDEUR=X`)
#           USDEUR=X.Open USDEUR=X.High USDEUR=X.Low USDEUR=X.Close USDEUR=X.Volume USDEUR=X.Adjusted
#2019-07-01       0.88000       0.88451      0.87970        0.87990               0           0.87990
#2019-07-02       0.88597       0.88678      0.88331        0.88594               0           0.88594
#2019-07-03       0.88567       0.88728      0.88454        0.88550               0           0.88550
#2019-07-04       0.88590       0.88697      0.88510        0.88590               0           0.88590
#2019-07-05       0.88605       0.89220      0.88590        0.88607               0           0.88607
#2019-07-08       0.89064       0.89219      0.88990        0.89068               0           0.89068
```

Comment: I get this error when running your code: Error in curl::curl_download(cu, tmp, handle = h) : Could not resolve host: finance.yahoo.com

Comment: @vicky I cannot reproduce the error, works with me every time I try it. Can you access finance.yahoo.com from your browser?

Comment: I think the issue is that I have proxy. Are you familiar with getQuote function? Is there any variable I can add to make getQuote(paste0(from, to, "=X")) output a specific date?

Comment: @vicky With `getQuote` the problem will remain, I think. And no, as far as I know to ask for dates it's `getSymbols`, not `getQuote`.